# Push Notify iPhone

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, php

I use this code to push:

```
push("xxxx", 3);

function push($deviceToken, $badge) {

    $message = "C'è il vento ideale!!";
    $sound = "default";

    // Construct the notification payload
    $body = array();
    $body['aps'] = array(
        "alert" => $message
    );
 
    if ($badge) {
        $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
    }

    if ($sound) {
        $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;
    }

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'apns-dev.pem');
    $fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp) {
    print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
        return;
    } else {
        print "Connection OK\n";
    }

    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $payload . "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

But this is the error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094414:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate revoked in /xxxx/notify.php on line 75
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: Failed to enable crypto in /xxxx/notify.php on line 75
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2196 (Unknown error) in /xxxxx/notify.php on line 75
> Failed to connect 0

Comment: it looks like your certificate isnt valid anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is explicit : `certificate revoked`.
Your certificate is not valid, the certificate is expired or you have clicked on 'revoke' the certificate in the Apple portal.
You may generate a new certificate for this appId, and install it on your server.